# JS: Get start and end dates months between two dates

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a student enrollment system where I need to get the months passed since enrollment date and I need to get the start and end dates of the all months passed to date.

```
let start_date = new Date('2022-01-24 15:00:00');

let months;
months = (current_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear()) * 12;
months -= start_date.getMonth();
months += current_date.getMonth();

let months_arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < months; i++){
    let start = new Date(start_date.setDate(start_date.getMonth() + i));
    let end = new Date(start.setDate(start.getMonth()+1));
    months_arr.push({'start': start, 'end': end});
}

return months_arr;
```

This returns a completely unexpected result:

```
    [
        {
            "start": "2021-12-12T20:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2021-12-12T20:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "start": "2021-12-12T20:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2021-12-12T20:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "start": "2021-12-12T20:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2021-12-12T20:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: 2 issues:  1) `.setDate()` changes the date.   2) `.setDate` changes the day of the month, but you're supplying it with the *month*.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update `.setDate` to `.setMonth`

```
let months_arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < months; i++){
    let start = new Date(start_date.setMonth(start_date.getMonth() + i));
    let end = new Date(start.setMonth(start.getMonth()+1));
    months_arr.push({'start': start.toISOString(), 'end': end.toISOString()});
}
```

to add months instead of days,
also i added `.toISOString()` to format start and end in [(ISO 8601)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)